# How can I ban a user from accessing my router?

Tags: wireless-router, blocking, user

How can I ban a user from accessing my router – or how can I end his session?

My router is a [D-LINK](http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=226) DI-514.

Comment: What is your routers model name, Because most routers allow you to mac address whitelist, but I can't give you a tutorial on that without knowing the router model. (to know if it supports it or not)

Comment: @Adam543i The model's in the link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add or change the wireless password to something more secure, and use a better encryption method, however that wont stop people that know what they are doing.

---

Here is an example of a D-LINK router's MAC address filtering page. http://support.dlink.com/emulators/wbr2310/adv_filters_mac.htm

To find your mac address (I'm assuming you are on windows) open `Command Prompt` and type `ipconfig` and look for your wireless/lan connection. Your MAC address is the `Physical Address` listed.